# Cannot connect to mongodb container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Hi I'm trying to develop simple api but I couldn't establish connection between api and mongodb. When I send a query to database it hangs and couldn't get response. I am trying to connect to mongo container with this code:

`mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo/micro-linkedin_api_1");`

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    restart: always
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongodb
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/xd/job-bot/api
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  scraper:
    build: ./scraper
```

and my folder structure is like this one :

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in docker-compose you defined 2 services:

`api` and `mongodb`

in Mongoose docs, this is how you connect:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

You did:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo/micro-linkedin_api_1");
```

so the `host` is not correct, you used `mongo` instead of `mongodb` as defined in docker-compose services.